# Using list comprehension to print converted string?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have been trying to use list comprehension to simplify this code:

```
c = 0
conv_regx = r'(Conv2d).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'
for layer in list(cnn):
     if "Conv2d" in str(layer):
         print(re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', str(layer)))
         c+=1
     if c == len(layerList['C']):
         break
```

But my attempts result in errors:

```
conv_regx = r'(Conv2d).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*?(\d+).*'
print_name = [str(re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', str(i))) if "Conv2d" in str(i) for i in list(cnn)]
```

Like this error:

```
    print_name = [str(re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', str(i))) if "Conv2d" in str(i) for i in list(cnn)]
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I properly use list comprehension for this task?

Edit:

I fixed the for and if mix up, but how do I print the string?

```
[print(str(re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', str(i)))) for i in list(cnn) if "Conv2d" in str(i) ]


    [print(str(re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', str(i)))) for i in list(cnn) if "Conv2d" in str(i) ]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The `if` clause in the list comprehension comes after the `for` clause.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I need to print the new string. This doesn't seem to work: `[print(str(re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', str(i)))) for i in list(cnn) if "Conv2d" in str(i) ]`

Comment: There is also no need to _cast_ the `re.sub()` result into a `str()` - it already is a string.

Comment: If you don't actually care about collecting all the strings in a list, using a list comprehension doesn't make much sense. Just use a `for` loop like in your original code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not always a good idea to *use* a list comprehension, but it is always a
good exercise to *create* one. Let's examine your code. You have a loop that 
should output `len(layerList['C'])` elements and then exit. You can use `itertools.islice` to get the desired number of elements from a generator.

Here's a first attempt:

```
import itertools    

def generator():
    for layer in list(cnn):
        if "Conv2d" in str(layer):
            yield re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', str(layer))

print (list(itertools.islice(generator(), len(layerList['C']))))
```

But you don't need to make a list from `cnn` because it is already iterable. 
And you don't need `layer` but only `str(layer)`. Why don't `map` every element
of `cnn` to a `str`?

```
def generator():
    for layer in map(str, cnn):
        if "Conv2d" in layer:
            yield re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', layer)
```

It also becomes very easy to convert the generator function into a generator comprehension:

```
g = (re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', layer) for layer in map(str, cnn) if "Conv2d" in layer)
```

And the final one-liner:

```
g2 = itertools.islice((re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', layer) for layer in map(str, cnn) if "Conv2d" in layer), len(layerList['C']))
```

It's clearer if you express `re.sub(...)` in a function:

```
def format_layer(layer):
    return re.sub(conv_regx, r'\3 \2 \4 \5', layer)

g = itertools.islice((format_layer(l) for l in map(str, cnn) if "Conv2d" in l), len(layerList['C']))
print (list(g))
```

But a loop may be more easy to understand and maintain...